# Is there a way to quantify the chirality of a 3d shape?

Tags: geometry

A propeller is a chiral structure. Propellers can have low or large pitch.
This difference can be seen as distinguishing propellers of low and of large chirality.

Is there a general way, given a closed 3d shape, to quantify its chirality? Is there some sort of integral over the shape that yields a number quantifying the degree of chirality of that shape?

Comment: The Hausdorff distance to its mirror image? Or rather, the inf of the distances to the confgruent copies of its mirror image, I guess.

Comment: In a word _yes_, though presumably the underlying intent is a measure satisfying additional conditions: 1. real-valued, 2. easily-calculated, 3. widely-used. Offhand I don't know of anything satisfying both 1. and 2., and nothing satisfying 3.

Comment: Where can I read more about the Hausdorff distance?

Comment: Complex-valued is also ok ...

Comment: For posterity: re-asked here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433487/is-there-a-way-to-quantify-the-chirality-of-a-3d-shape